# How to implement a loop in php

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

Hi I'm totally new here and with and would glad if someone could help as I'm stuck with how I can create a loop with some php code.

```
$TotalUniques = $this->TotalUniquesHits($Counts[$xx]['ID']);
```

The value I'm after is `[$xx]` which represents a position in the array. How to change it so that I get `$TotalUniques` looping through all the values of `$xx`?

Comment: It might help if you provided some context by posting some of the surrounding code.

Comment: To o11c, Sean O'Toole, suslov, greg-449, karthik I asked a question and got an answer in the first reply. Implies I got my message across. I wonder why my post is flagged but I would very much have it deleted as my question was on coding and not grammar.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `foreach` loop:

```
foreach($Counts as $xx){ 
    $TotalUniques[] = $this->TotalUniquesHits($xx['ID']);
}
```

You may also consider checking if each `$xx` has `ID` key with `isset` or `array_key_exists`.